# Display checked rows in ng-repeat irrespective of filter

Tags: angularjs

Each of the character names listed has a checkbox against it.
The contents of the div updates according the text entered into the search box.

If I check "Harry" in the div, and then enter "Tom" into the search bar, "Harry" disappears from the div.
If I then erase the text ("Tom") inside the search bar, "Harry" reappears in the div. However the checkbox adjacent to it is no longer checked.

What I want instead is that the names that are checked should never disappear, irrespective of what the search text is. Also the checked entries should appear at the very top of the list in the div.

At all times, there should be a maximum of 5 entries in the div.

Can someone please advise me on how to achieve this?

app.js

```
$scope.characters =  [
    { id: 1, name: "Dexter" },
    { id: 2, name: "Harry" },
    { id: 3, name: "Ronald" },
    { id: 4, name: "Ginny" },
    { id: 5, name: "Tom" },
    { id: 6, name: "Hermione" },
    { id: 7, name: "Severus" },
    { id: 8, name: "Marvolo" },
    { id: 9, name: "Sirius" }
];
```

page.html

```
<input type='text' ng-model='searchText' placeholder='Search'>

<div ng-repeat='char in characters | filter: searchText | limitTo: 5'>
    <input type='checkbox' id='{{ char.id }}'>
    <span>{{ char.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For keeping the state of the checkbox you need to use the `ng-model` directive on your checkbox input:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model="char.checked" id='{{ char.id }}'>
```

To have checked elements at the top add an `orderBy` filter to the `ng-repeat`. For the filtering you can write your own filter (I put it inside the controller, but you can of course add it as a *proper* filter, too):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="char in characters | 
  filter: showCharacter | 
  orderBy: 'checked' | 
  limitTo: 5">
```

**JS** (in your controller)

```
$scope.showCharacter = function(character) {
  if (character.checked) {
    return true; // Keep element if it is checked
  }
  if (_.startsWith(character.name, $scope.searchText)) {
    return true; // Keep element if it matches search text
  } else {
    return false; // Remove element otherwise
  }
};
```

**Note:** I used lodash's `_.startsWith` function for simplicity, you can obviously replace this with any other method for checking if your search text matches the name of the character.

You can see the whole thing in action in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qeluhupobo/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The orderBy" 'checked' part doesn't seem to be working correctly though. If I check an entry,  it rises to the top as expected. So if there are multiple checked entries, they all rise to the top and then order themselves according to default order, which is all good.

However if I then uncheck any one of those checked entries, it rises to the top.

It is as if there are three categories - unchecked, checked and freshly unchecked (in order of increasing priority).

Comment: Issue solved. The problem was that `character.checked` has no default value. So the order of the rows became - 'false' (freshly unchecked), 'true', ''. To rectify that, I included the following statement to set its default value to false -

`if (!character.checked) { character.checked = false; }`

Then inside `ng-repeat`, I modified orderBy to `orderBy: '-checked'`. That did it. :-)

Comment: You're right, sorry for that. Seems like Angular puts undefined values at the top when sorting. Good catch!

Comment: No probs. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: How can I keep a particular checkbox (say the one with id 3) checked by default? It can of course be unchecked and checked later.

I tried using `if (character.id === 3) character.checked = true;` inside `$scope.showCharacter`; but that obviously didn't help since it results in the checkbox being always checked.

What should I do?

Comment: Just modify your `characters` array when the controller is initialized: `[..., {id: 1, name: "Ronald", checked: true}, ... ]`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that. Whether or not a checkbox will be checked will depend upon whether its corresponding id belongs to a particular set in my database. The checked status can be different for different sets. Hence using a `checked` property in the characters object is not an option.

Comment: Any tips on how to achieve the above?

Comment: The `checked` property in the `characters` array which I suggested does not need to be there permanently. This is exactly what a controller is supposed to do: Modify your data to be displayed in your view!